# How to Send Bulk Email Using ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need send once a month automatic login and password to the registered users on our web page to facilitate access on our products and services.

But I'm afraid to generate spam on the net and I thought about sending the message for single user in a block of email e.g. 25 messages for each time.

Possible query mysql code:

```
Select CustomerID,ContactName,Address,Phone,Email from customers 
Where email_sent = 0 LIMIT 25;
```

For each time the field email_Sent is update to 1 for the 25 users email and then the next 25 users.

How to realize this idea with c# asp net?

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write a windows console and then schedule to run from  task schedule of windows. in task schedule set trigger monthly.

in mail server:

first you should know that dkim and spf for email are ok.

you can send an email to a gmail account for testing. then in gmail go to "show original" and see they are pass.

[image to show spf and dkim pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPnN8.png)

if you can add ptr record. it will help to prevent spam
in body of email:
you should write address and unsubscribe link in email.
in code:
you should set email is bulk.in c# sample code:

```
 var mailtest = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("", ""),
                    Subject = toSend.DirecMessageSubject,
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                };
```

mailtest.Headers.Add("Precedence", "bulk");`